# Usage of Array in Sql Possible?

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a stored proicedure that gets all the townID's from Region_TownPage table. Then i should get the City, Stateinitials of all the townID's.

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTownDetailsforRegionID]
@RegionID int

AS
BEGIN
Declare @townID int

    set @townID = (Select townID from Region_TownPage where regionID =@RegionID) 

SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Select City, StateInitials,TownID from TownPage where TownID =@townID 


END
```

I do not know how to use an array here in sql. If someone could help me doing this, i really appreciate that.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need an array - you just need to join the tables?

```
Select r.RegionId,
       t.TownId,
       t.City, 
       t.StateInitials

From Region_TownPage r
Join TownPage t on r.TownId = t.TownId
Where r.RegionId = @RegionId
```

Comment: Assuming this question is his actual query I would agree this is the best approach. Otherwise the other answer of using a table might be preferable depending on complexity of query

Comment: agreed. this would be the way to do it unless you needed to keep the townIDs in memory for something in the SP later on but for your small example, a join would be the better solution.

Answer (score 4):

you would declare a table variable instead of an int. so it would be something like

```
DECLARE @tab table(townID int)

INSERT INTO @tab
SELECT townID from Region_TownPage WHERE regionID = @RegionID

Select * From TownPage WHERE TownID IN(SELECT townID FROM @tab)
```